# Numpy array of u32 to binary bool array

Tags: numpy

I have an array:

```
a = np.array([[3701687786,  458299110, 2500872618, 3633119408],
              [2377269574, 2599949379,  717229868,  137866584]], dtype=np.uint32)
```

How do I convert this to an array of shape `(2, 128)` where `128` represents the binary value for all the numbers in each row (boolean dtype) ?

I can sort of get the bytes by using list comprehension:

```
b''.join(struct.pack('I', x) for x in a[0])
```

But this is not quite right. How can I do this using numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do bitwise `and` with the powers of `2`:

```
vals = (a[...,None] & 2**np.arange(32, dtype='uint32')[[None,None,::-1])

out = (vals>0).astype(int).reshape(a.shape[0],-1)

# test
out[0,:32]
```

Output:

```
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Comment: Thanks, though I am not sure if this is correct. The first number ```3701687786``` should be converted to ```11011100 10100011 01000101 11101010``` according to [here](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_unsigned_int.html?decimal=051055048049054056055055056054). This is not the same as ```out[0, :32]```-

Comment: A, probably, I got the little indian order. For big indian, try `[None, None, ::-1]`

Comment: Ok, it looks correct now :)